# How to get value return from stored procedure laravel?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some problem with my laravel, I want to get the generated data but I always get null.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_generated_showidea_id]
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @errormessage as nvarchar(100);
    DECLARE @showidea_id as nvarchar(50);
    DECLARE @type as nvarchar(2)

    SET @type = 'IP' 

    EXEC sp_sequencer_transaction @type, @showidea_id OUTPUT

     IF @showidea_id IS NULL OR @showidea_id = '' 
     BEGIN
         SET @errormessage = 'Didnt generated data';
         RAISERROR (@errormessage, 16, 1);
         RETURN;
     END    

     SELECT @showidea_id
END
```

I just want to get that `showidea_id` when I input it into laravel here I got null

Controller.php:

```
$showidea_id = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->select('sp_generated_showidea_id');
dd($showidea_id);
```

Is there something wrong with my stored procedure?

Comment: You're not executing the stored procedure from Laravel, try: `$showidea_id = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->select('exec sp_generated_showidea_id');`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line with this one:

@showidea_id = Exec sp_sequencer_id @type

Unless the procedure is designed to give output using an output method, then you just review @Return.

Good luck.

Comment: that, didn't work, my sp_sequencer has 2 parameter, first is the type that's will be hardcoded and the seconds is paramter that will return value using output here is my sequencer https://pastebin.com/CP9fUaZK